# Cross translation unit use of inline function declared but not defined in a header file in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, inline

First, let me say that it's not helpful telling me that what I'm trying to do is dumb or bad style or that I need to rearrange my code.  I'm working on someone else's codebase; I have a very limited ability to change things in this.  I'm just trying to get it to work in a new environment.

I'm working on compiling code that was developed with C++-MSVC-Windows.  I'm trying to get this to work with C++-GCC-Linux.  The existing codebase uses many instances of 'inline' tagged functions used across translation units where the declaration is common and the use is ubiquitous, but the definition lives in only one translation unit (i.e. one .cxx file).  I've read in various online resources that it's possible to get inline functions to work across translation units this way in GCC using Link Time Optimizations (i.e. gcc -flto), but I'm not able to get it to work.  The online resources I've found are very weak in explaining exactly what the syntax is to get it to work.  I don't know if I'm misreading the stuff I've found, or if it's just not possible to get this to work, but certainly I haven't managed to get it to work yet.

BTW, I've been told that in MSVC-Windows this ends up with the code actually inlined in places it's not defined in, but I haven't actually looked at the emitted binary to see that for myself.  I suppose it's possible that MSVC isn't actually inlining and just doesn't error on this.

Here's the smallest version of the problem:

file: func.hxx

```
inline int func();
```

file: func.cxx

```
#include "func.hxx"
inline int func()
{
    return 1;
}
```

file: main.cxx

```
#include "func.hxx"

int main()
{
    return func();
}
```

With -flto:

```
gcc -fpermissive -std=c++17 -flto main.cxx func.cxx
In file included from main.cxx:1:
func.hxx:1:19: warning: inline function 'int func()' used but never defined
    1 | inline int func();
      |            ^~~~
/usr/bin/ld:  /tmp/ccuZDsOM.ltrans0.ltrans.o: in function 'main':
<artificial>:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to 'func()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Without -flto:

```
gcc -fpermissive -std=c++17 main.cxx func.cxx
In file included from main.cxx:1:
func.hxx:1:19: warning: inline function 'int func()' used but never defined
    1 | inline int func();
      |            ^~~~
/usr/bin/ld:  /tmp/cc4x65H5v.o: in function 'main':
main.cxx:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to 'func()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The only difference with -flto seems to be where the intermediate assembly lives.

Also, I've tried scattering extern here and there, but can't find any permutation that makes a difference.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no easy workaround here. Not defining an `inline` function in a translation unit where it is used makes the program IFNDR (illf-formed, no diagnostic required). A compiler is allowed to still compile the program correctly, but doesn't need to. GCC doesn't emit inline functions into object files at all if all their uses have been inlined in the translation unit, so the linker has nothing to work with. Easiest solution is fixing the code by removing `inline` on these functions, I guess.

Comment: I suspect that you've misunderstood what you read about `-flto`.  I have no doubt that it can perform inlining optimizations for functions defined in a translation unit other than the ones in which calls appear, but that's a different thing from making the compiler accept programs that do not conform to the standard's requirement that non-member functions *declared* `inline` and called must be defined in the same TU.

Comment: compile with `-Dinline=` and see what happens.

Comment: Correction for my comment above: I think the program is actually ill-formed, not IFNDR, if the `inline` function is odr-used, but not defined, in a translation unit. (I would need to look it up in the standard again.) In that case MSVC is actually not standard-conforming by not emitting any diagnostics for this. (I think it is actually an intentional language extension fot backwards-compatibility from before the standard's specification of `inline`. If I remember correctly there is a compiler flag to disable it.)

Comment: @KamilCuk Wow, the nuclear option! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you read e.g. [this `inline` specifier reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) this is the very first point in the [explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline#Explanation):

> The definition of an inline function ... must be reachable in the translation unit where it is accessed

That means you need to define the inline function in all translation units where you call it.

If the existing code-base doesn't follow that then it needs to be fixed to become standards-compliant.

Comment: I concur: fix the code.

Comment: Like I said when I opened the question, suggesting I change the code or the layout of the code is not helpful.  It works where it currently is used.  I don't own the code and I'm not allowed to change it.  It's not my codebase to fix.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @TimWilliams Then there's really nothing you can do, except report it as a bug to the project owners (because it *is* a bug in their project).

Comment: Nope, not a bug because it works perfectly in their (MSVC) environment.  And it works according to the definitions from MSDN, it's not just a lucky break.  It's the way the MSVC compiler is specced to work.

COompile with the /GL flag, link with the /LTCG flag, voila, it works

Comment: @TimWilliams All compilers tend to add non-portable and non-standard extensions to the C++ language. If you want to be able to use multiple compilers in multiple environments then you can't keep using such extensions. So either you continue to lock yourself into MSVC and Windows, or you refactor the code to make it portable.

Comment: Yeah, obviously I'm going to have to figure something out.  But for the owner of the code, who only cares about MSVC+Windows and is only sparingly allowing changes, this is not a bug.  It's just me being a pain in the project.

Comment: What's more likely to be acceptable is for me to #define INLINE to inline on MSVC and nothing on GCC and then accept that my GCC compile isn't suggesting inline to the compiler on GCC.

Comment: @TimWilliams Is this work-related? Are there requirements about portability? Then you have to bring this up with your bosses, team leads, etc. Otherwise, if it's just to make life simpler for you, lobby for the portability to your bosses and leads to add it as a requirement ;). Some arguments that might help your cause: As a non-standard and non-portable extensions this might actually be removed at any time by Microsoft, meaning you not only lock yourself into a single ecosystem, but also a specific version of that ecosystem. And it will be *much* cheaper to fix now, rather then later.

Comment: Project is 30+ years old and already deeply tied to Windows eco-system, starting way back from Windows NT.  This is more of a skunk-works.  That's why I stressed when asking the question that the answer "don't do it that way" is not helpful.  Not sure why I'm getting that answer, frankly.  I don't think the question could have been much clearer that doing it this way on Windows is a constraint, not a free-variable that I can change.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SPD's answer, here's a possible workaround:

```
#define inline
#include "func.hxx"
#undef inline
```

That will cause the opposite other problem though, if there are inlined function *bodies* in `func.hxx`.